# Getting the document.body of new window after using window.open()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, instagram

The main goal was to fetch/GET req a url (like a url to an IG reels) and it returns the HTML document. Since this isn't possible due to CORS,
I'm trying something out as a workaround:

1. Function activates with window.open() with desired URL
2. Window Opens to URL
3. set a string variable to the document.body of the newly opened page

However,  I seem to be having a hard time capturing this.  I've tried a variety of different approaches (element.innerHTML/outerHTML/innerText, etc..) with no luck.

Here's a page with my example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-41zdxs?file=index.html

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is a `headless browser`. Check out [phantomjs](https://phantomjs.org/)

Comment: Thank you.  I think this is it.  Gonna explore with puppeteer

Comment: Ended up going with Cheerio.  Fetched with Axios.  Thank you!